# Limiting the scope of interactions that can be done with ChatGPT via openai api

Tags: python, openai-api

I would like to limite the scope of questions which can be answered by chatGPT. I am trying to code something like this:

```
    session["chat_history"] = [
                                  {"role": "system", "content": "You can only answer some stuff in literature and arts subject"},]
    new_message = {"role": "user", "content": question}
    session["chat_history"].append(new_message)

    response = client.chat.completions.create(
               model=model,
               messages=session["chat_history"],
               temperature=temperature,
               max_tokens=max_tokens,
               )
```

Variables defined as  model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0.7, max_tokens=1000

The problem is... Even something is out of scope it is answering... For example, a question about basic maths os even how to build a pool... How do I limit it?

Would like to add that I am using lib version 1.12

Regards

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: Funnily enough, this is pretty much the same class of problem that even the best machine learning researchers can't answer satisfactorily right now. Otherwise alignment would be solved I guess

Comment: Something naive would be to ask ChatGPT, whether the prompt only covers the allowed topics or not, and answer with "0" if not, and "1" if so. And you'd relay the prompt to the model directly only if you get a "1" before. But that's not really safe, and immediately doubles your costs.

Comment: This is really a guardrail question (based on specific prompts and specific LLM settings such as temperature), or an app-level issue (e.g. *your code* submits prompts to your LLM, based on fixed input choices for an end-user) and there's no way to provide you with an absolute, objectively-correct way to specify such settings for your use case. But... at least now you know the area of study you need to focus on.